# Vue.js trigger event when input field becomes enabled

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following vue.js element

```
<input
    v-else-if="input.type == 'hidden'"
    @input="emitHidden"
    type="hidden"
    :value="input.value"
    :disabled="!enabled"
/>
```

However, because it is a hidden field, the `@input` event never fires.

How would I be able to run `emitHidden` when the value becomes enabled?

Comment: Use the type text and hide it using the class attribute instead.

Comment: You can use v-show instead `v-show="input.type == 'hidden'"` instead of v-if